# How to prevent BottomNavigationView (that is setup with Navigation Component) from changing destinations an item click

Tags: android, listener, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I have a `BottomNavigationView` setup with Navigation Component, and I want to intercept the handling of changing destinations on pressing an item, and prevent it from changing destination on a certain condition.

For example: Showing a dialog if the user is navigating to a destination and he's not signed in.

How do I do that?

I can't seem to be finding a listener that could be called `OnDestinationChange` with some sort of boolean returned to inform the navigation component that it should go ahead with the navigation or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do so using navigation component methods, **but there is an easy workaround that doesn't break navigation flow**.
on your bottom navigation view get the menu and set onItemClickListener and return true if you don't want the navigation component to receive the click hence no navigation happens
here is example

```
binding.bottomNav.menu.findItem(R.id.searchFragment)?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            if(viewModel.isUserAuthorized()) {
                false // here this will allow navigation component to consume the click
            }
            else {
                 showUnauthorizedUserDialog()
                 true // here this will prevent navigation component from consuming the click
            }
}
```

additionally according to docs of **onMenuItemClick**

> @return Return true to consume this click and prevent others from
> executing.

Comment: I've used this approach, but still, the navigation component will still going to be reacting to the click, no matter what the returned result from the menu item click listener is.

Comment: I've had so much trouble trying to fix issue to the point that I had to make a REAL workaround to make this working. I made a custom bottom navigation, that inflate views in front of the menu items, and those views absorbs the click... And then I assign a click listener to the view that is in front of the option that the user should not be able to navigate to on certain condition like a guest user, and remove the click listener if the user is backed to authorized state.

Comment: can you try adding `setOnMenuItemClickListener ` before bottomNav.setupWithNavController, maybe order matters, because i have done this solution and it works just fine.

Comment: Hey, I've tried your method once again and I followed it exactly how you described it. Turns out I've been using it wrong since the beginning. I've been returning false the whole time thinking that it would consume the click. Thank you for your detailed answer, and I'm marking this as the accepted answer cause it looks to be working perfectly.

Comment: Also, I've tried reordering the methods as you suggested. Doesn't really make any difference as long as the listener is set.

Comment: Also, I don't think that this is a workaround. I don't think that the navigation component's responsibility to check for any conditions before invoking navigation. It's the view wrapping the navigation, which is in our case the bottom nav bar.